# is it possible for a third-Party to develop Android Accessibility Service with Real-Time Speech Recognition for Live Captions-like Functionality

Tags: java, android, kotlin, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I am developing an accessibility service application and **I need functionality similar to the live captions in Android,** I am able to build an accessibility service similar to talkback i.e. I can able to access the data displayed in a screen similar to talkback, but now **I need to** **get data from the microphone too**, to improve my accessibility service application, **similar to live captions**, but I couldn't find any resources for it, am I missing something or is it possible for any third-party to build an application similar to live captions?

Comment: Are you trying to build your own speech recognition, or simply to use something already built?  If you're trying to do the first one, yes, that's possible, just hire a dozen PhDs and have them work on it for a couple years.

Comment: or how to use the present live captions? can i get data from it?